# Using a CTE within an UPDATE statement that is using a CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
WITH CTE_List AS
(
SELECT B.Chain_Code, B.State
FROM Company.dbo.Company_Master AS A
LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.StateChain_List AS B
ON A.State = B.State
AND A.Chain_Code = B.Chain_Code
)

UPDATE Company.dbo.Company_Master
SET MFN_Ind = (
    CASE
        WHEN (CTE_List.Chain_Code IS NULL) AND (CTE_List.State IS NULL) THEN 'N'
        ELSE 'Y'
    END
)
FROM CTE_List
```

The select statement in CTE_List returns values like this, but corresponding to every record in the Company_Master table:

```
Chain_Code | State
00992      | IL
NULL       | NULL
NULL       | NULL
00732      | MA
NULL       | NULL
```

My ultimate goal is to update the MFN_Ind column in Company.dbo.Company_Master based off this CTE_List. If Chain_Code and State are populated, then MFN_Ind = 'Y'. If Chain_Code and State are NULL, then MFN_Ind = 'N'.

As it's set up now, the query updates the MFN_Ind column with everything set as 'Y' so clearly the the first portion of the CASE is not catching the NULL fields. Any tips on how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: If the right-side chain code and state are null, how are you really joining these tables?

Comment: The chain code and state are not actually null in the StateChain_List or in Company_Master. What I want in CTE_List is basically just a list of all the records in Company_Master. Where the chain code and state is filled in, that means that record's chain code and state in Company_Master match one of the chain code and states in StateChain_List. When the values are null, that means that the chain code and state in Company_Master do not match any of the chain code and states in StateChain_List. Then in the UPDATE I can just update each record based on whether or not it's null or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this far more complex than it needs to be.

```
UPDATE m
  SET m.MFN_Ind = CASE WHEN l.State IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
FROM Company.dbo.Company_Master AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company.dbo.StateChain_List AS l
ON m.State = l.State
AND m.Chain_Code = l.Chain_Code;
```

Or maybe better to just split it up into 2 - update all the rows to `N`, then update the matching rows to `Y`:

```
UPDATE Company.dbo.Company_Master SET m.MFN_Ind = 'N';

UPDATE m SET m.MFN_Ind = 'Y'
FROM Company.dbo.Company_Master AS m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Company.dbo.StateChain_List AS l
WHERE m.State = l.State
AND m.Chain_Code = l.Chain_Code);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH CTE_List AS
    (
    SELECT B.Chain_Code, B.State
    FROM Company.dbo.Company_Master AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Company.dbo.StateChain_List AS B
    ON A.State = B.State
    AND A.Chain_Code = B.Chain_Code
    )

    ---UPDATE THE RECORD

    UPDATE m
    SET MFN_Ind = (
        CASE WHEN (CTE.Chain_Code IS NULL) AND (CTE.State IS NULL) THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
        END
    )
    FROM CTE_List cte 
  INNER JOIN  Company.dbo.Company_Master m 
    on m.State =cte.state
```

Comment: This will only update rows where state is *not* null in the CTE. Everything else will be filtered out on the inner join.

Comment: Use a Left outer join instead of INNER JOIN. It should work just fine.